# Pointer on class contructor

Tags: c++, std

I'm working on a personal project and I need to have a dynamic factory.
Currently I have the following "system" :

```cpp
class Action { ...} // Which is abstract
class A : public Action { ... }
class B : public Action { ... }
class C : public Action { ... }

...

std::map<std::string, Action *> _actions;
_action.insert( { "A", new A() } );
_action.insert( { "B", new B() } );
_action.insert( { "C", new C() } );

Action * act = _actions.find("B")->second; // Get action's pointer
```

But I'm not satisfied by this solution because, even if I never use these actions, they are instantiated at boot and stay in memory during all the application's life-cycle and if I want to have a "clean" object, I need to cast dynamically my object to determine its type to call the constructor by copy... I'm not really fan of this solution because I must "hard code" all cases...

I don't know if the solution that I imagine is really feasible but here is my idea :

I conserve the previous class hierarchy, which is :

```cpp
class Action { ...} // Which is abstract
class A : public Action { ... }
class B : public Action { ... }
class C : public Action { ... }
```

But I want to use the map differently :

```cpp
std::map<std::string, POINTER_ON_CLASS_CONSTRUCTOR> _actions;
_actions.insert( { "A", &A::A } );
_actions.insert( { "B", &B::B } );
_actions.insert( { "C", &C::C } );

Action * act = new (_actions.find("B")->second);
```

To resume my idea :

I want to map a key with a pointer on each constructor I want to map and then, instantiate dynamically an action-based object according to the key.

Thanks per advance for your help and if you have a suggestion to solve this issue, do not hesitate to submite it :)

---

Context :

I'm creating a CLI for my software and if I want to code this solution is to map the first word of an action with a associated action.

Example : If I enter "add file.txt", "add" will be the key of my map to retrieve a "clean" instance on the class "AddAction" (which is a child of Action - which is abstract and common to all action-based class).

Edit : before posting this question, I've searched on the web and on this forum but I haven't found what I was looking for.. :/

Comment: I removed that STL tag since you do not appear to be using the SGI STL. See [What's the difference between “STL” and “C++ Standard Library”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5205491/whats-the-difference-between-stl-and-c-standard-library)

Comment: Add a static factory method to each class that just calls `new` and store pointers to those.

Comment: The address of a constructor may not be taken - [constructors have no names](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the clone idiom to avoid having to `dynamic_cast` objects to determine which copy constructor to call, eg:

```cpp
class Action {
public:
    virtual ~Action() {};
    virtual Action* clone() = 0;
    ...
};

class A : public Action {
public:
    Action* clone() { return new A(*this); }
    ...
};

class B : public Action {
public:
    Action* clone() { return new B(*this); }
    ...
};

class C : public Action {
public:
    Action* clone() { return new C(*this); }
    ...
};

...

std::map<std::string, Action*> _actions;
_action.insert( { "A", new A } );
_action.insert( { "B", new B } );
_action.insert( { "C", new C } );

Action *act = _actions["B"]->clone(); // see Note below...
...
delete act;
```

<sup>Note: There is no reason to use `map::find()` when you are not validating the returned iterator.  It would be easier to just use `map::operator[]` instead, or `map::at()` if you want to throw an error if the specified key is not found.</sup>

However, if you do not want to store actual objects in the `map`, you can use factory functions instead (you can't obtain a pointer to a constructor), eg:

```cpp
class Action { ... }
class A : public Action { ... }
class B : public Action { ... }
class C : public Action { ... }

...

using ActionFactoryFunc = Action* (*)();

std::map<std::string, ActionFactoryFunc> _actions;
_action.emplace( "A", []() -> Action* { return new A; } );
_action.emplace( "B", []() -> Action* { return new B; } );
_action.emplace( "C", []() -> Action* { return new C; } );

Action *act = _actions["B"]();
...
delete act;
```

---

Lastly, you really should be using `std::unique_ptr<Action>` instead of raw `Action*` pointers, eg:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class Action {
public:
    virtual ~Action() = default;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Action> clone() = 0;
    ...
};

class A : public Action {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Action> clone() override { return std::make_unique<A>(*this); }
    ...
};

class B : public Action {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Action> clone() override { return std::make_unique<B>(*this); }
    ...
};

class C : public Action {
public:
    std::unique_ptr<Action> clone() override { return std::make_unique<C>(*this); }
    ...
};

...

std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<Action>> _actions;
_action.emplace( "A", std::make_unique<A>() );
_action.emplace( "B", std::make_unique<B>() );
_action.emplace( "C", std::make_unique<C>() );

auto act = _actions["B"]->clone();
...
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <memory>

class Action { ... }
class A : public Action { ... }
class B : public Action { ... }
class C : public Action { ... }

...

using ActionFactoryFunc = std::unique_ptr<Action> (*)();

std::map<std::string, ActionFactoryFunc> _actions;
_action.emplace( "A", []() -> std::unique_ptr<Action> { return std::make_unique<A>(); } );
_action.emplace( "B", []() -> std::unique_ptr<Action> { return std::make_unique<B>(); } );
_action.emplace( "C", []() -> std::unique_ptr<Action> { return std::make_unique<C>(); } );

auto act = _actions["B"]();
...
```

Answer (score 7):

You could map the names to factory functions, then call those functions each time you want to create a new instance. Wrapping it in a `unique_ptr` will give you the destruction you want after use. [live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/am5fx6gy8NRJ3oV3)

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<Action>()>> ACTIONS = {
  {"A", [] { return std::make_unique<A>(); }},
  {"B", [] { return std::make_unique<B>(); }},
  {"C", [] { return std::make_unique<C>(); }}
};

int main() {
  auto action = ACTIONS["A"]();
}
```